# Access an XML file in /App_Data folder of my WCF service?

Tags: xml, wcf, app-data

How do I access an XML file I added to /App_Data folder in my WCF Service?

Comment: are you hosting your service on iis?

Answer (score 4):

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "App_Data", "data.xml");
```